# Unable to add a var in a php function

Tags: php, function

I am fairly new to PHP but i am running into a problem with the following:
i am trying to add a `$var` in the `strtotime()` function. Like such:

```
        $var= $_POST['yyyy'] . $_POST['MM'] . $_POST['DD']; 
        //function 
         Function blah() {
            strtotime($var);
            $time = $date -time();
            $numberofDays = ceil($time / 86400); 
            return $numberofDays;
            }
```

How do i put the `$var` in the `strtotime` function?

Comment: pass the $var to blah($var), and then actually call the function

Comment: `Function blah()` does not have `$var` defined inside of it. and `strtotime` returns value to nothing.

Comment: Use 'global $var;' inside the function to use the variable.

Comment: Do not use globals if you don't absolutely have to.. The answer provided below is the correct way to do this, simply introduce $var to the function scope by passing it in as an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$var` is out of scope to your function. You need to pass it as a parameter for the function to have access to it. You're also missing the declaration and assignment of a value to `$date` which I am assuming is the first line of your function.

```
$var = $_POST['yyyy'] . $_POST['MM'] . $_POST['DD']; 
function blah($var) {
    $date = strtotime($var);
    $time = $date -time();
    $numberofDays = ceil($time / 86400); 
    return $numberofDays;
}
echo blah($var);
```

Comment: +1 For being faster, and you also need to actually call the function

Comment: @Kypros You're actually right about making sure to call the function. I should assume nothing.

Comment: Better "blah" then "blech", I guess. (grin)

Comment: @JohnConde Edit `like` to `Kike`?? :P

Comment: I would've written "Pike", cuz it's a skip away from "L".

Comment: The anticipation is killing me, unlike the old Heinz commercials. When's that going to turn to a green ticky?

Comment: Thanks for the help! adding $var as parameter for the function fixed the problem.

Comment: I stand corrected ;) Still, you gotta love those old Heinz ketchup commercials ;) Where has Carly gone to?

Comment: `global $var;` on the first line inside the function also works.

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 Yes, but that is considered a bad programming practice